# Large file handling - Read algorithm breaks - C#

Tags: c#, .net, large-files

So I've got an algorithm that reads from a (very large, ~155+ MB) binary file, parses it according to a spec and writes out the necessary info (to a CSV, flat text). It works flawlessly for the first 15.5 million lines of output, which produces a CSV file of ~0.99-1.03 GB. This gets through hardly over 20% of the binary file. After this it breaks, as in suddenly the printed data is not at all what is shown in the binary file. I checked the binary file, the same pattern continues (data split up into "packets" - see code below). Due to how it's handled, mem usage never really increases (steady ~15K). The functional code is listed below. Is it my algorithm (if so, why would it break after 15.5 million lines?!)... are there other implications I'm not considering due to the large file sizes? Any ideas?

(fyi: each "packet" is 77 bytes in length, beginning with a 3byte "startcode" and ending with a 5byte "endcode" - you'll see the pattern below)

*edit* code has been updated based on the suggestions below... thanks!

```
private void readBin(string theFile)
{
    List<int> il = new List<int>();
    bool readyForProcessing = false;

    byte[] packet = new byte[77];

    try
    {
        FileStream fs_bin = new FileStream(theFile, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs_bin);

        while (br.BaseStream.Position < br.BaseStream.Length && working)
        {
            // Find the first startcode
            while (!readyForProcessing)
            {
                // If last byte of endcode adjacent to first byte of startcod...
                // This never occurs outside of ending/starting so it's safe
                if (br.ReadByte() == 0x0a && br.PeekChar() == (char)0x16)
                    readyForProcessing = true;
            }

            // Read a full packet of 77 bytes
            br.Read(packet, 0, packet.Length);

            // Unnecessary I guess now, but ensures packet begins
            // with startcode and ends with endcode
            if (packet.Take(3).SequenceEqual(STARTCODE) &&
                packet.Skip(packet.Length - ENDCODE.Length).SequenceEqual(ENDCODE))
            {
                il.Add(BitConverter.ToUInt16(packet, 3)); //il.ElementAt(0) == 2byte id
                il.Add(BitConverter.ToUInt16(packet, 5)); //il.ElementAt(1) == 2byte semistable
                il.Add(packet[7]); //il.ElementAt(2) == 1byte constant

                for(int i = 8; i < 72; i += 2) //start at 8th byte, get 64 bytes
                    il.Add(BitConverter.ToUInt16(packet, i));

                for (int i = 3; i < 35; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(il.ElementAt(0) + "," + il.ElementAt(1) +
                        "," + il.ElementAt(2) + "," + il.ElementAt(i));
                }

                il.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle "bad" packets
            }
        } // while

        fs_bin.Flush();
        br.Close();                
        fs_bin.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Your code is silently catching any exception that happens in the while loop and swallowing it.

**This is a bad practice because it masks issues like the one you are running into.**

Most likely, one of the methods you call inside the loop (`int.Parse()` for example) is throwing an exception because it encounters some problem in the format of the data (or your assumptions about that format).

Once an exception occurs, the loop that reads data is thrown off kilter because it is *no longer positioned at a record boundary*.

**You should do several things to make this code more resilient:**

1. Don't silently swallow exception in the run loop. **Deal with them.**
2. Don't read data byte by byte or field by field in the loop. Since your records are fixed size (77 bytes) - read an entire record into a byte[] and then process it from there. This will help ensure you are always reading at a record boundary.

Comment: +1, reading the record in its entirety is a good idea. You could even wrap that array in a `BinaryReader` over a `MemoryStream` and still get the convenience of the built-in conversion functions.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i implemented some changes based on what you've said and i edited the original to show the updated code. however, the problem still hasn't been fixed. when i ran it before the code changes, i once got an EndOfStreamException which i thought was weird. currently, the same problem exists but there are no errors thrown at all. any thoughts?

Comment: Things to check: 1) is your test file corrupt? Try a different file if you have one. 2) are some records a different size than 77 bytes? Manually examine the data in the region of the file you're dealing with, 3) is there a logic error in the code? try skipping the first 15.5 million records (don't process them just fast forward the stream) and single-step in the debugger to see what's happening

Comment: to answer your questions: 1) it is not a corrupt file. i will generate another one for testing, though that takes approx 12 hrs. 2) all records up to and after this break are 77 bytes in length...  3) i skipped ahead and discovered that a few million bytes after it breaks, i find a packet length 78 bytes which throws things off later (however unrelated to initial "breaking" problem).. which means my problem is 2-fold (see next comment - apologies if double commenting is against site policies): my reader and writer both break after a certain length (variable, around 100 million bytes)

Comment: i thought my reader was fixed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595325/serialport-data-loss-c after implementing hardware handshaking. it seems not. i'm still using what's presented in the 2nd chunk of code. my code handles incorrect packet lengths by filling in all "0"s instead of actual data (not shown). however, the reader still breaks (cuts off in the middle of a packet) after a certain length regardless of where in the stream i begin processing (this time after 24.5 million lines of output). note there are 32 lines of output per packet if that's relevant.

Comment: update (sorry for triple post now!): it seems this "breaking" issue may be due to my text editors not being able to open files of these sizes. opening the same file with a different amount of memory usage in the system as a whole produces text files of varying lengths. i may be interpreting the text editor's memory handling as a fault in my code. i'm working on testing this somehow, possibly with new text editors in combination with breakpoints

Answer (score 3):

- Don't put an empty generic `catch` block here and just silently catch and continue. You should check and see if you're getting an actual exception in there and go from there.
- There is no need for the `byteToHexString` function. Just use the `0x` prefix before a hexadecimal number and it will do a binary comparison.

i.e.

```
if(al[0] == 0x16 && al[1] == 0x3C && al[2] == 0x02)
{
    ...
}
```

- I don't know what your `doConvert` function does (you didn't provide that source), but the `BinaryReader` class provides many different functions, one of which is `ReadInt16`. Unless your `short`s are stored in an encoded format, that should be easier to use than doing your fairly obfuscated and confusing conversion. Even if they're encoded, it would still be far simpler to read the `byte`s in and manipulate them, rather than doing several roundtrips with converting to strings.

**Edit**

You appear to be making *very* liberal use of the LINQ extension methods (particularly `ElementAt`). Every time you call that function, it enumerates your list until it reaches that number. You'll have much better performing code (as well as less verbose) if you just use the built-in indexer on the list.

i.e. `al[3]` rather than `al.ElementAt(3)`.

Also, you don't need to call `Flush` on an input `Stream`. `Flush` is used to tell the stream to write anything that it has in its write buffer to the underlying OS file handle. For an input stream it won't do anything.

I would suggest replacing your current `sw.WriteLine` call with this:

`sw.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(packet));` and see if the data you're expecting on the row where it starts to mess up is actually what you're getting.

I would actually do this:

```
if (packet.Take(3).SequenceEqual(STARTCODE) &&
    packet.Skip(packet.Length - ENDCODE.Length).SequenceEqual(ENDCODE))
{
    ushort id = BitConverter.ToUInt16(packet, 3);
    ushort semistable = BitConverter.ToUInt16(packet, 5);
    byte contant = packet[7];

    for(int i = 8; i < 72; i += 2)
    {
        il.Add(BitConverter.ToUInt16(packet, i));
    }

    foreach(ushort element in il)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", id, semistable, constant, element);
    }

    il.Clear();
}
else
{
    //handle "bad" packets
}
```

Comment: ahh that makes things much easier. thanks for the heads up. the original code has been edited to reflect the updates, but the original problem still remains :\

Comment: thanks much for the good advice. i am very new to c# and appreciate the info - much easier, both on mem usage and my code. in addition, your suggestion write out the entire packet.ToString() led to the discovery of my possible text editor memory handling problem (see comments above to LBushkin's reply). *hopefully* (pending investigation) now my only issue is that either my binary writer is having an issue or the device sent an invalid packet